# Unity - Android NDK not found -- was manually installed

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-ndk, oculusquest

I am trying to code for Meta Quest 2 via Unity.  Every time I try to build, I get an error that the proper NDK isn't installed.  I have researched this and found advice to download it and then manually install.  I installed it to the path described in External Tools within Unity.  I've restarted everything since then, but continue to get the same error every time.  I followed the advice and links at this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html.

I have researched this and found advice to download it and then manually install.  I installed it to the path described in External Tools within Unity.  I've restarted everything since then, but continue to get the same error every time.  I followed the advice and links at this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html.

I've also seen similar posts here and have tried advice in those posts.

I do have the MetaQuest in Developer Mode, not sure what the next step is.

Answer (score -1):

In the past I've got problems requiring NDK or SDK replacement. In the end what happened to solve it for me was upgrading to latest stable release of Unity. Be sure to use latest stable version as some plugins don't work with older versions anymore and might lead to a rabbit hole of installing other SDK or NDK for no reason.